# Office 2010 moved from Old Computer to new computer will load but not operate

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

I have office 2010 on three computers. I just replaced two of them and installed Office 2010 from my disc. The first one worked fine. The second computer loaded Office 2010 but when I go to use Outlook, it will populate my emails but not allow me to reply or forward them. A box pops up that says buy a new Office License. Microsoft will not support 2010. Is there anything that I can do to get it to work?

Comment: There are a variety of solutions for this available from Microsoft and other places. What have you tried so far? https://www.google.com/search?q=cannot+activate+office+2010+license

Comment: Are you using a single license on the three computers? If so, is that permitted by the license terms?

Answer (score 0):

You may refer to the suggestion of Simon Jones in the thread below:

[Can I move Office 2010 from my old PC to new PC this fall?](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/664a30b1-a13f-4003-af44-834deb028d3b/can-i-move-office-2010-from-my-old-pc-to-new-pc-this-fall?forum=officeitproprevious)